# pandas describe of describe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, describe

I have a DataFrame and there are two columns. One of it is the names and another one is some number. I need to count mean of it for every unique name.

Tried `.describe()`, but it shows only for all DataFrame, not a unique names. If anyone could help, I would be thankful.

Comment: Please show a small piece of your dataframe, together with the output of describe and the output that you would like instead